# Is this a delay circuit? / Which resistor is responsible for load impedance?

Tags: delay, input-impedance

I just stumbled upon this circuit of a microphone preamp. However, I`m not entirely sure about two of its components/ properties.
[image: INA217 preamp]
My first question regards R3 and its closely located capacitor. Someone online claimed this was in order to reduce any clicking when phantom power is switched on, and after some googling I found that this might be a simple delay circuit. Am I correct in thinking that?

My second question regards R4/ R5. I´m aware that these together with C1/ C2 form a high-pass filter, but someone told me these would also present a load impedance of 2.2k to the microphone. Since impedance is still quite the conundrum to me, I thought I´d ask here wether that is correct.
I was under the impression that R1/ R2 not only limit the current to be drawn from the 48V supply, but also play a role in the input impedance of this circuit. This is because that´s what I gathered from the diagram here http://educypedia.karadimov.info/library/mic1dat.pdf where a 2.2k resistor in series with the 2V supply indicate a 2.2k load impedance in the table above said diagram.

I apologize for the convoluted question and many thanks in advance for your help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R3 simply connects R1,R2 to ground when phantom power is switched off, and the C simply provides some decoupling on phantom power. No delay, and I would expect quite a thump when switching on phantom power.

R4,R5 provide a 4.4K load (leg to leg) on the microphone, or 2K2 on each leg - and you are absolutely right that this impedance is further reduced by R1,R2 which are effectively in parallel (for AC) with R4,R5.

And phantom power is always supplied from 48V in series with 6.8k on each leg - it's a de-facto standard that studio mics are designed to. It's not primarily current limiting (though it does that too), but to keep the impedance on the audio signal reasonably high.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are the INA needs a DC reference for the input pins. R4/R5 provide that.

Datasheet says the input bias current is 2uA nominal, 12uA worst case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would have totally overlooked that if it wasn´t for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Well no, the mid point is grounded so it doesn't really form a circuit

the capacitor looks like supply decoupling

the resistor is possibly to stop the switch from arcing, 48V DC is quite a lot to switch and having ground opposite power on a change-over switch is asking for trouble, 47K limits the current to about 1mA, which is not enough to sustain an electric arc.

C1,C2, R4,R5 do form a high pass filter, have you calculated the corner frequency? it'll be sow low as to be inaudible)  the purpose of those two capacitors is to block the 48V DC so it doesn't get into the amplifier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I did calculate the cutoff frequency. If I´m not mistaken it should be 1.54Hz in order to block the 48VDC?

Comment: yean, so it's not going to impact the sound quality. the purpose is to block the 48VDC.